# What are elements in no namespace in CSS?

Tags: css

This is an exemple in [CSS Namespaces](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-namespaces-3/#css-qnames):

> Given the namespace declarations:
>
> ```css
> @namespace toto "http://toto.example.org";
> @namespace "http://example.com/foo";
> ```
>
> In a context where the default namespace applies
>
> - `toto|A`: represents the name A in the http://toto.example.org namespace.
> - `|B`: represents the name B that belongs to no namespace.
> - `*|C`: represents the name C in any namespace, including no namespace.
> - `D`: represents the name D in the http://example.com/foo namespace.

What is an exemple of `B` in a HTML document? What is an exemple of `|B` as a CSS selector?

I tried with a custom element, but it seems declared in the (default) XHTML namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have case B in a pure, valid HTML document. You can in an XML document.

We can add an element in no namespace using createElementNS() in script. (Doing so means the document is no longer valid HTML).

```css
|B {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<B>foo</B>
<script>
  const b = document.body.appendChild(document.createElementNS('', 'B'));
  b.appendChild(document.createTextNode('bar'));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It would have been usefull to have this explanation on MDN (for exemple). *To create an element without specifying a namespace URI, use the createElement() method* does not mean the same thing than creating an element in "no namespace".

Comment: @cdoublev - That's a distinction that's been through a number of variations in the DOM spec. Historically, createElement() did create elements in no namespace. But that didn't work for HTML documents in browsers. So the current DOM spec says for [createElement()](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createelement) - "Let namespace be the HTML namespace, if this is an HTML document or this’s content type is "application/xhtml+xml"; otherwise null. " where "null" means in no namespace.